# How to enable extensions on an Azure App?

Tags: azure

I have activated an app service and a mysql database on microsoft azure.

What I would like to do now is activate the phpmyadmin extension in order to use it for database management.

The problem is that the Extensions item is always disabled from the Azure app service menu.

Following online directions I successfully created a new mysql connection string using this format:

```
Database=DBNAME;Data Source=MYSQLHOST;User Id=USERID;Password=PWD;
```

Despite this, the Extensions item is still disabled. 
I have also restarted the app but nothing has changed.

Following the path advanced tools > go for the kudu I get this:
https://ibb.co/txKDCPY

Answer (score 4):

If the **Extensions** on the App Service menu is greyed out, you could go to the Kudu site to add the extension you want.

On the App Service menu, choose **Advanced Tools**, click **Go**. You will see your app's Kudu site, on the top of the bar , you could find the Site extensions. Then choose Gallery and search the extensions you want like phpmyadmin. Then you could clike the **+** button to install the extension.

[image]
[image]

**Update**: [msdn answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/cac05673-eeb7-46d5-968d-24f00674bc97/why-is-extensions-grayed-out-on-my-wep-app-linux-resource-in-portal-ui?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

[image]

Comment: when I follow the path I get a different page called azure app service and there is no site extensions. I show only some information on the enviroment and rest api.

Comment: @zed87, where is the page?

Comment: @zed87, please paste the picture, I couldn't open your kudu site, it's not authorized.

Comment: @zed87， your web is in linux, for now this feature is not available for linux, , i update my answer, you could find it from the picture and in the answer it said the unsupported feature is grey.

Comment: @zed87, if this could help you, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it might be that you are using a linux web app.  As such, the phpmyadmin is installed as part of the docker image.

To load phpmyadmin you should visit /phpmyadmin.

The credentials are available under the application settings on the web app itself.

More details : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/06/07/mysql-in-app-feature-for-web-apps-on-linux/

Comment: yes i am using linux web app. can you be more specific about where i can find phpmyadmin?

Comment: @zed87 if your website is 
myappname.scm.azurewebsites.net, then it should be, 
myappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpmyadmin.  The login details are in the application settings tab in the Azure portal.  See linked article in the answer.